# web service address for Jenkins on AWS Windows installed as a Windows Service

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, jenkins, windows-services

I have just installed Jenkins (as a Windows Service) on AWS Windows (Win Server 2012R2) instance.

I'm able to launch it via browser using http://localhost:8080

What url should I use to access this server from other client? I have tried http://:8080 or without the port number but my client (over the net) is failing to connect. The Public DNS of the AWS is also not working.

I set up another Jekins on AWS Ubuntu server with apache tomcat and it's connecting just fine using the Public DNS of the AWS Ubuntu server.

Comment: I have also tried installing Tomcat to host the Jenkins before trying to do it as a Windows Service. Same issue.

Comment: that is... <Public IP>:8080 or <Pubic DNS>:8080 that I've tried and failing.

Comment: If your <Public IP> is failing, then you have to verify that Windows Firewall allows this connection.

Comment: Disabled both inbound (from server) and outbound (from client) Firewall and the connection keeps timing out still...